# Plotting last layer of raster stacks

Tags: raster, r

I have multiple raster stacks that are being generated with different numbers of layers. I want to create an object that only includes the last layer in each stack based on nlayers. Right now I am doing it manually by calculating the number of layers and creating an object like so:

```
f <- function(ii){
  
  if(is.na(ii[1])) ii[1] <- 0
  
  cumsum(na.locf(ii))
  
}
CumMar2000 <- calc(ChlMar2000,fun = f)
Cum2000Mar<-CumMar2000ML$layer.31
```

`ChlMar2000` is a stack of daily chlorophyll data for March and `layer.31` shows the total accumulated chlorophyll for the month of March.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I want to create an object that only includes the last layer in each stack based on nlayers."

Solve the simpler problem first. Now do you get the last layer of a single stack?

```
lastlayer = function(s){s[[nlayers(s)]]}
```

"create an object that only includes the last layer in each stack"

How do we go over each stack and apply a function? Make a list and `lapply` the function:

```
lastLayers = function(stacklist){
  lapply(stacklist, lastlayer)
}
```

That returns a list of raster layers, so we may want to stack them:

```
lastLayers = function(stacklist){
  do.call(stack, lapply(stacklist, lastlayer))
}
```

To test, make a 3x4 raster of numbers 1:12:

```
r = raster(matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
```

Then make three stacks of varying layer numbers, and so we can tell what we're getting I'll multiply the last layer by its name number:

```
s1 = stack(list(r,r,r,r,r,r))
s2 = stack(list(r,r,r*2))
s3 = stack(list(r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r*3))
```

Now try my function:

```
> lastLayers(list(s1,s2,s3))
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 3, 4, 12, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.25, 0.3333333  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
names      : layer.6, layer.3, layer.9 
min values :       1,       2,       3 
max values :      12,      24,      36
```

That returns three layers, and I can tell from the min-max of each layer that I must be getting the correct (last) layer out of the items in the list of stacks. The layer names, incidentally, tell me the name and number of the last layer in each stack. This may vary for your data.

Comment: Thank you very much!